# App getting crashed on button click.

Tags: ios

My .h file is as given below

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "ScrollTestViewController.h" @interface EliteScreen : UIViewController


 - (IBAction)eliteII_BtnClk:(id)sender;

 @end
```

My .m file is as given below

```
    #import "EliteScreen.h"
    #import "EliteQuestionScreen.h"
    #import "NextView.h"
    #import "ScrollTestViewController.h"
    @interface EliteScreen ()

    @end

    @implementation EliteScreen{

       NSArray *viewArray;
    }


     - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
          // Custom initialization
      }
       return self;
     }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
      [super viewDidLoad];
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.


    }

   - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
   {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }







    - (IBAction)eliteII_BtnClk:(id)sender {


      ScrollTestViewController* optimztionscreen1 = [[ScrollTestViewController alloc]
      initWithNibName:@"ScrollTestViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
     NSLog(@"ahbjcdcx");
     [[self navigationController] pushViewController:optimztionscreen1 animated:YES];

  }



     @end
```

And my ScrollTestViewController.h is as below

```
          #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
          #import "EliteQuestionScreen.h"

          @interface ScrollTestViewController : UIViewController

           @property(strong,nonatomic)EliteQuestionScreen *opt;

          @end
```

And my ScrollTestViewController.m is as below

```
  #import "ScrollTestViewController.h"
  #import "EliteQuestionScreen.h"

      @interface ScrollTestViewController ()

     @end

       @implementation ScrollTestViewController

       - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
       {
          self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
         if (self) {
             // Custom initialization
        } 
         return self;
       }

      -  (void)viewDidLoad
      {
        [super viewDidLoad];
          // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
          [self addSubViewToScrollView];

      }

       - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
       {
          [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
         // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
      }

         -(void)addSubViewToScrollView{

              CGFloat x = 0;
              UIScrollView *scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc]
              initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
               self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
              NSInteger viewcount= 8;

            for(int i = 0; i< viewcount; i++) {
             // EliteQuestionScreen* optimztionscreen = [[EliteQuestionScreen alloc]
                  initWithNibName:@"EliteQuestionScreen" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

               self.opt = [[EliteQuestionScreen alloc] 
       initWithNibName:@"EliteQuestionScreen" 
         bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                 if (i == 0) {
                x  = self.opt.view.frame.origin.x;
              } else {
                x = self.opt.view.frame.size.width + x;
             }
             NSLog(@"I %d",i);

             UIView *viewMine = self.opt.view;
            viewMine.frame = CGRectMake(x, 0, self.opt.view.frame.size.width,  
            self.opt.view.frame.size.height);
           [scrollview setPagingEnabled:YES];
           [scrollview addSubview:viewMine];

       }
         scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width *viewcount,    
        self.view.frame.size.height);
   [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
       NSLog(@"MY VALUE FOR X %f",self.view.frame.size.width *viewcount);
    }




@end
```

And my eliteQuestionscreen.h file is as below

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

  @interface EliteQuestionScreen : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,     
   UITableViewDataSource>
 {
     UITableView *tableview;
   }

  @property (nonatomic, assign) UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets;


 - (IBAction)noBtn:(id)sender;

   @end
```

And My EliteScreenQuestion.m file is as below

```
       #import "EliteQuestionScreen.h"  
       #import "AppConstant.h"
      #import "SimpleTableCell.h"
      #import "PopUpController.h"
      #import "AssetPopUpController.h"
       #import "BrowseProgrammingTools.h"
      #import "NextView.h"
      @interface EliteQuestionScreen ()

     @end

      @implementation EliteQuestionScreen
    {
     NSArray *tableData;
     NSArray *thumbnails;

     }

      - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
     {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
         }
      return self;
   }

     - (void)viewDidLoad
     {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        [self setFontOnText];



     tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:first_screen_firstBtn_title, 
     first_screen_secondBtn_title,first_screen_thirdBtn_title, nil];

    thumbnails = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"assetImage_iPad.png",   
         @"assetImage_iPad.png",
              @"assetImage_iPad.png",nil];


   }







 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
  (NSInteger)section
 {
     return [tableData count];
 }

  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

         SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView 
              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil)
    {
         NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell"
        owner:self options:nil];
         cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
     }


     cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails 
     objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

     [cell.nameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"UniversLTStd-BoldCn" size:13.00f]];
     [cell.nameLabel sizeToFit];
     return cell;
  }

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
   *)indexPath{

      SimpleTableCell *newCell = (SimpleTableCell*)[tableView 
      cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

     NSString *Abc = newCell.nameLabel.text;
      NSLog(@"MY  TIME %@",Abc);

       AssetPopUpController* optimztionscreen = [[AssetPopUpController alloc] 
   initWithNibName:@"AssetPopUpController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
          [self.navigationController presentViewController:optimztionscreen animated:NO
   completion:nil];
      optimztionscreen.assetTitle.text = Abc;
      [optimztionscreen.assetTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"UniversLTStd-BoldCn" 
      size:20.00f]];
     [optimztionscreen.assetTitle sizeToFit];

 }

 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  
   *)indexPath
 {
     return 65;
  }


      -(void)setFontOnText{

  }



     - (IBAction)noBtn:(id)sender {

         [self createTableViewForNO];

   }

  -(void) createTableViewForNO{

      tableview=[[UITableView alloc]init];
      tableview.frame = CGRectMake(555,456,149,269);
      tableview.dataSource=self;
       tableview.delegate=self;
      [tableview registerClass:[SimpleTableCell class] 
      forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SimpleTableCell"];
      [tableview reloadData];
      [self.view addSubview:tableview];
 }



      @end
```

Whenever i perfom no button click in EliteQuestionScreen application crashes bad error is

```
 [EliteQuestionScreen performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7586c60
```

Comment: Please try to post only relevant code where you are getting issues and problems. You have included all your code in this post.

Answer (score 0):

In `ScrollTestViewController.m` you do:

```
self.opt = [[EliteQuestionScreen alloc] 
       initWithNibName:@"EliteQuestionScreen" 
         bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

viewcount times.

All but the last of those is getting released.  The last one is retained in self.opt.  If you try to reference the other ones, you will crash.

There isn't a simple fix here.  You are trying to utilize a `UIViewController` nib for its views, and this is not a good way to do so.  Looking through the code, I think you may need to rethink your architecture.  For example, instead of loading this view controller n times, you may wish to switch to a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView`.